# Sed move first to end

Tags: bash, unix, sed

How do you move the first word to the end with bash?

```
eg. "super duper"
=> "duper super"
```

Text will always be two words.

Comment: Will the text always just be two words?  In other words, what is the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly shorter version with `awk`. It will swap the first and last words regardless of number in between

```
awk '{t=$1;$1=$NF;$NF=t}1'
```

#### Output

```
$ echo "super califragilisticly duper" | awk '{t=$1;$1=$NF;$NF=t}1'
duper califragilisticly super
```

Comment: Why the `1` after the curly braces?

Comment: @DanFego That's a shortcut for `{print $0}` since `1` always evaluates to TRUE and the default action for `awk` is to print the current line.

Comment: Would `awk '{print $2,$1}'` fit the bill?

Comment: @potong for the exact question at hand, yes it would. I decided to take it one further (with minimal additional code) to make it work regardless the number of words.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
sed -e "s/\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\)/\2 \1 /g" filename
```

Get a capturing group for each word and each and then swap them with their back references.

Comment: An extra space has crept in as well as the `g` flag.

Answer (score 1):

#### With Bash:

```
while read -r word1 word2
do
echo "$word2 $word1"
done <<< "super duper"
```

**not tested** answering via phone

Comment: +1 This is actually the best answer since `word2` will contain all the rest of the line (in the case of more than two words) and the result will be as the title of the question requests "move first to end" rather than only a simple two-word swap. The reason this answer is better than the other similar answer is because of the use of `-r` with `read` and the variables are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

in straight sh, for two words:

```
swapwords() {
    echo $2 $1
}

swapwords super duper

=> duper super

swapin() {
    read first last
    echo $last $first
}

echo super duper | swapin

=> duper super
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using shell tools:

```
ghoti@pc:~$ tac -b -s\ <<< "super duper" | paste - -
 duper  super
```